# Oracle => PostgreSQL: Array of %ROWTYPE?

Tags: arrays, oracle, postgresql, database-migration

Is there any way in PostgreSQL to declare local type `"TABLE OF ..%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER"` inside a function like in Oracle?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FNC
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
   TYPE TYPE_TB IS TABLE OF ADM_APPLICATIONS%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   TB_VAR   TYPE_TB;
BEGIN
   return 1;
END;
```

Comment: This looks like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How about describing what you are trying to achieve instead?

Answer (score 0):

For every table there is also a corresponding type (with the same name) available.

So you can do the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc()
   RETURNs integer
AS
$$
declare
   tb_var adm_applications[];
begin
   return 1;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! And then one more question: how to set and get field value? This way doesn't work : `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc()
   RETURNs integer
AS
$$
declare
   tb_var adm_applications[];
begin
   tb_var[1].col_name:= 'LALALA';
   return 1;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;` It says : "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 5:    tb_var[1].col_name:= 'LALALA';"  @a_horse_with_no_name